# Add gradient to react circular progress bar

Tags: reactjs, progress-bar

I have been working on creating some circular progress bar for my simple dashboard. Basically, I am using react-circular-progressbar as I find it user-friendly. It works fine but I want to add some gradient to its stroke with either CSS or something else maybe. Here is a code snippet to get things clear :

```
<CircularProgressbarWithChildren value={78} styles={{ root: {}, path: { stroke: "#6D6CB8" } }} >
<span style={{ color: "#6D6CB8" }}>78<tspan>%</tspan></span>
</CircularProgressbarWithChildren>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47426782/add-gradient-background-color-along-with-stroke-css

Comment: Thanks for your response. Unluckily, the component I am using in this project is imported from react and that is all the more reason why I am unable to add gradient to the svg element.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using `react-gradient-progress` to achieve this. 
It is similar to `react-circular-progressbar` with a gradient setting.

https://medium.com/better-programming/build-beautiful-gradient-enabled-circular-progress-bars-in-react-d0a746deed0

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-gradient-progress